# Fourier Series of $\sin(x)$ on the Interval $(-1,1)$

Tags: calculus, fourier-series

I am tasked with finding the real form of the Fourier series where $\phi(x)=\sin(x)$ on $(-1, 1)$.  So far I have the following:

Since $\sin(x)$ is an odd function, it has a Fourier sine series such that

$$\phi(x) = \sin(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n \sin(nx) \textrm{ for } x \in (-1,1)$$
and
$$b_n = \frac{2}{l} \int_{0}^{l} \phi(x)\sin(\frac{n\pi x}{l})dx$$

Substituting $\phi(x) = \sin(x)$ and $l=1$ gives

$$
\begin{align*}
    b_n &= 2 \int_{0}^{1} \sin(x)\sin(n\pi x)dx && \\
        &= \frac{2\cos(1)\sin(\pi n) - 2\pi n\sin(1)\cos(\pi n)}{\pi^2 n^2-1} \\  
        &= -\frac{2 \pi n \sin(1)(-1)^n}{\pi^2n^2-1} && \textrm{ for } n^2 \neq \frac{1}{\pi^2}
\end{align*}
$$

$\therefore$ The real form of the Fourier series $\phi(x) = \sin(x)$ on $(-1, 1)$ is

$$
\begin{align*}
    \sin(x) &= 2\pi \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n \sin(1)\sin(nx)(-1)^{n+1}}{\pi^2n^2-1}
\end{align*}
$$

But when I [compute the value of the series](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+of+%5B2*pi*n*sin%281%29sin%28n%2F2%29%28-1%29%5E%28n%2B1%29%5D%2F%5Bpi%5E2*n%5E2-1%5D+from+n%3D1+to+infinity) for $x=\frac{1}{2}$ I get

$$\sin(1/2) \approx 0.15848388659160$$

Which is incorrect. What gives?

Comment: $2$ isn't a period of $\sin(x)$. @Arthur seems the OP is extending the function so it wouldn't be sinusoidal outside the interval $(-1,1)$

Comment: Oh woops, I should've had $\sin(n\pi x)$ instead of $\sin(n x)$ I believe. I misinterpreted this [reference](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierSineSeries.html).

Comment: I think other than the missing $\pi$ in the $\sin$, it's fine. https://www.desmos.com/calculator/aohjlgucke

Comment: The integral looks wrong. $sin(x)sib(n\pi x)=(cos(x(1+n\pi))-(cos(x(1-n\pi)))/2$.   The rest of the derivation is no good.

Comment: @herbsteinberg What looks wrong about it?

Comment: Changing the product into a sum of two cosines leads to a different integral.   $b_n=\frac{sin(1+n\pi)}{1+n\pi}-\frac{sin(1-n\pi)}{1-n\pi}$.  This does not look  like what you have.

Comment: @herbsteinberg Use the identities for $\sin(x)$ listed [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometricAdditionFormulas.html) and put the fractions over a common denominator to get the result listed above.

Comment: You are right!  As for your calculation, shouldn't the sum use $sin(n\pi x)$, not $sin(nx)$?